# can we assign subdomain name to SetEnvIf variable

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on multi vendor e-commerce website with separate sub-domain for each vendor.

can we set sub-domain name to environment variable?

like if sub-domain is test 
MEGA_RUN_CODE=test

I have created static solution
SetEnvIf Host test.host MEGA_RUN_CODE=test
but I want it dynamically set sub-domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setup env variables dynamically using:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^([^.]+) MEGA_RUN_CODE=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it's not working for me.
ca we set using SetEnvIf
like SetEnvIf Host test\.localhost MAGE_RUN_CODE=test dynamic ?